# PHP how to use micro-time as order id, need micro-time in 9 digit encode/decode formula.

Tags: php, algorithm, time, microtime

I used http://www.epochconverter.com/date-difference

```
From 1/1/2000, 12:00:00 AM (epoch: 946665000)
To(current time) 8/11/2016, 12:00:00 PM (epoch: 1478586600)

Difference in seconds:      531921600
```

used this seconds: 531921600 difference as order id so based on order id i can get what time it will created an order
but i need more accurate order id with micro-time in 9 digit only.
Kindly give me any suggestion or formula to get micro-time in 9 digit only and unique every time

Comment: So, what have you tried? Show us your work.

Comment: @たぬき i tried php encode functions and compressed functions. but it will not giving me output as expected, also tried some math's operation to get it in 9 digit but no success. Need some formula to get micro-time in 9 digit